# how to change record or field separator of a file

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

How can I change the record separator of a file? For example, concatenating multiple lines into a single line, by changing record separator from newline to space. Another example is to split a line at its space into multiple lines, by changing record separator from space to newline.
What env variables control the record separators? IRS and ORS?

Similarly, how can I change the field separator of a file?
Do env variables IFS OFS work with `cat`?

Comment: Is this all specific to awk?

Comment: No - one could say similar things about perl.

Comment: It's just a little misleading to ask about "environment variables" that are unique to specific utilities without mentioning those utilities. Is the question asking which UNIX utilities support env vars named IRS, ORS, IFS, or OFS? Or how to change field / record separators in a specific utility ?

Comment: I have often wondered why no one ever picked up the habit of using ASCII characters FS, GS, RS, and US (0x1C - 0x1F) for their obvious purpose.  (As well as SOH, STX, ETX.  (0x1-0x3))

Answer (score 4):

Record- and field-separator behavior can be set in *certain* programs such as `awk`, and rarely is done via environment variables.  Common utilities such as `cat` do not have this type of feature: only programs which are documented (such as `cut`) have options for using different record or field separators.

`awk` is the most flexible of those mentioned, with variables which can be set for both record- and field-separators:

> **`FS`**
>       Input field separator regular expression; a *`<space>`* by default.
>   **`OFS`**
>       The print statement output field separator; *`<space>`* by default.
>   **`ORS`**
>       The print statement output record separator; a *`<newline>`* by default.
>   **`RS`**
>       The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a *`<newline>`* by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a *`<newline>`* plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a *`<newline>`* shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.

You could set those variables within the script, e.g.,

```
awk ' BEGIN { RS=" "; } { print; }' < inputfile
```

to print each word of a file on a new line.  You can also assign to any variable using the `-v` option:

```
awk -v  RS=" " '{ print; }' < inputfile
```

Finally, `awk` also has an option `-F` (input field separator) which is the same as the `FS` variable.

Further reading:

- [awk - pattern scanning and processing language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)
- [cat - concatenate and print files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html)
- [cut - cut out selected fields of each line of a file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html)

Comment: can you give examples using awk

Comment: For example to replace newlines with spaces (e.g. concatenate lines) using awk: `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} {print $0}' your_input_file`.

Comment: Thanks. How would you change record separator from space to newline

Comment: Record separator is normally a newline.  If you want a *field* separator to be a newline, you'd use the `-F` option with a newline as value (awkward but portable).

Answer (score 2):

If you are only concerned with replacing characters, you can have a look at the `tr` utility (which stands for "translate").  For example, to convert newlines to spaces you can use:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < your_input_file
```

Similarly, to translate spaces to newlines use:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < your_input_file
```

Note that `tr` reads from `stdin`, so you either need to use input redirection (`<`) like I did in these examples, or pipe your input into it (using `|`).